# how to show Html inside validation summary?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core

I'm trying to show model validation as HTML. but my attempt always shows text. And here is my attempt.

**Action** here is where I add key and value to the Model summary

```
ModelState.AddModelError("ExistUserButNotConfirmed", CurrentUserLog.ExistUserButNotConfirmed);
```

**View** here where I made many attempts to show that error

```
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
<span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="ExistUserButNotConfirmed"></span>

@*@Html.Raw(Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ExistUserButNotConfirmed).ToString())*@

@if (Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ExistUserButNotConfirmed) != null)
{
    @Html.Raw(Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ExistUserButNotConfirmed))
}

@if (Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ExistUserButNotConfirmed) != null)
{
    @using System.Web;
    @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ExistUserButNotConfirmed).ToString()))
}
```

**Model** here where I store the Html text format by which I need to show in the view

```
public string ExistUserButNotConfirmed { get; set; } =    

@"<div class='card text-center'>
    <div class='card-header'>
        Your information are correct but your email isn't confirmed yet.
    </div>
    <div class='card-body'>
        <h5 class='card-title'>
            please, To activate your account
        </h5>
        <p class='card-text'>
            check out your Email to confirm your account <br />
            OR <i class='bi bi-arrow-down-short'></i>
        </p>
        <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary'>Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
    <div class='card-footer text-muted'>
        <a formnovalidate asp-action='ReSendEmail' asp-route-Email='' id='ReSendEmail' title='Re-Set your Email' class='float-end text-danger border-0 bg-transparent'>
            Re-Send Activation Email
            <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='25' height='25' fill='currentColor' class='bi bi-arrow-repeat' viewBox='0 0 16 16'>
                <path d='M11.534 7h3.932a.25.25 0 0 1 .192.41l-1.966 2.36a.25.25 0 0 1-.384 0l-1.966-2.36a.25.25 0 0 1 .192-.41zm-11 2h3.932a.25.25 0 0 0 .192-.41L2.692 6.23a.25.25 0 0 0-.384 0L.342 8.59A.25.25 0 0 0 .534 9z' />
                <path fill-rule='evenodd' d='M8 3c-1.552 0-2.94.707-3.857 1.818a.5.5 0 1 1-.771-.636A6.002 6.002 0 0 1 13.917 7H12.9A5.002 5.002 0 0 0 8 3zM3.1 9a5.002 5.002 0 0 0 8.757 2.182.5.5 0 1 1 .771.636A6.002 6.002 0 0 1 2.083 9H3.1z' />
            </svg>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>";
```

**Result**

[image: result]

Comment: `Html.ValidationMessageFor` uses **plain text error messages as its *input***, and produces **HTML as its *output***. If that is unacceptable to you then you may need to implement a variant of this method that behaves in a different way, but I would recommend not fighting this convention, it's much easier to just adopt it.

Comment: You you tried using `string builder` on your backend code? Could you please  share your backend code?